# Return an element within a for-each outside it in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, return

I would like to return an element of a `List` that I loop through with a for-each loop , outside the loop.

Here is my method :

```
private List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<Taxi>();
Taxi scheduleTaxi(){
     for (Taxi taxi : taxis){
         if (taxi.isFree()) {
            return taxi;
        }
     }
    return null; //I would like it to return taxi not null
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your code already does what you want. You're already returning the first free taxi inside the loop, and returning null if there are no free taxis.

Comment: Well, you have an entire list of `Taxi`, which one do you want to return?

Comment: I did a test and it always return null it does not return a free taxi

Comment: So that implies no taxis are free.  Again, in that case, which taxi should be returned?

Comment: Then that means isFree is always returning false, or your list is empty (which it is, in your example, since you never add any taxis to it). What you shouldve done before asking this question is either stepped through in a debugger or added some temporary printouts in the loop to display what is happening.

Comment: @Takichiii well of course. Your list is empty and the method goes straight to `return null;`

Comment: Hint: you could be returning a LIST of free taxis;then you dont worry about nulls or so. Or, you could look into Optionals.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response, i solved the problem. Indeed, my code works well even if i dunno why (i tought it would always return null )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've wrote is exactly right (you could be getting null because there aren't any that's free I guess) but here's another simple way of doing it to help you understand the concept.

Assign the `Taxi` that's `isFree()` to a reference and return that outside the for-loop like this,

```
private List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<Taxi>();
Taxi freeTaxi = null;
Taxi scheduleTaxi(){
     for (Taxi taxi : taxis){
         if (taxi.isFree()) {
            freeTaxi = taxi;
            break; //since you already found what you want, no need to keep going.
        }
     }
    return freeTaxi;
}
```

Comment: great thanks!! do you know why in my code it doesn't always `return null` even if it's the last return? and which one of the codes has the best quality?

Comment: You can only return once from a function, the moment "return taxi;" executes it has gone out of the function, it'll skip every line after it. However, if that doesn't happen, it'll keep going till the end of the function or until it encounters the next return statement.

Comment: Thanks! so i guess your snippet is better because it contains only one `return`

Comment: I wouldn't say better. It's just another way of returning value back from a function. You can either have multiple return statements in the function or a single return statement but you keep assigning different values to that reference based on your conditions. I personally prefer method two :)

Comment: IMO the original implementation of the method is ever-so-slightly better than what this one provides: it's more condensed and easier to read. And this one still can return `null` for all the same reasons.

Comment: @nasukkin I framed the code this way to help OP grasp the concept of return and he's got that cleared. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you aren't asking how to return from inside an iterative loop, but are trying to avoid returning `null` if no suitable match is found, correct...? It makes sense, I suppose; I've had some colleagues who were opposed to working with null for whatever reason.

One approach you can take is the "sentinel value" approach, as one of my mentors once called it (might be there's a better name for it). Basically, you have one specific `Taxi` instance that represents the absence of a Taxi entirely. In your Taxi class...

```
public class Taxi {
    public static final Taxi NO_TAXI = new Taxi(/*constructor params here*/);

    // Insert the rest of your class here!
}
```

Basically, you want to initialize a globally-accessible, constant Taxi instance that represents the concept of not being a Taxi. Users of your class can look to that instance and know "Oh, this means that there was no Taxi."

So, your original `scheduleTaxi` method would look something like this:

```
private List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<Taxi>();
Taxi scheduleTaxi(){
    for (Taxi taxi : taxis){
        if (taxi.isFree()) {
            return taxi;
        }
    }
    // No free taxi found! Return the no-taxi instance.
    return Taxi.NO_TAXI;
}
```

Make sure you include that the method will return NO_TAXI if no free taxi is found, so that your users won't be confused!

I personally prefer to just work with `null`. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok, if the question is related to "*should I return a null reference*??", then its OK.

if you change a little the name of the method and add a good java doc, like>

```
public Taxi getAvaliableTaxi(){
     for (Taxi taxi : taxis){
         if (taxi.isFree()) {
            return taxi;
        }
     }
    return null; //I would like it to return taxi not null
}
```

then I can see that it could be possible that no taxis are avaliable or free by the time I call the method.. so null is defenitely a valid return type
Is my responsability as client of your API to check the return before I jump in a null-Taxi...